# How can I add ask username and password feature to only one of my laravel routes?

Tags: laravel, authentication, routes

I have created a few forms in laravel. I want to restrict access to one of them only to a specific user.

I want to create a user and password myself.

This is my routes excerpt. This is the route I want to protect from access

```
Route::get('/tabledata_id_title', 'KedivimController@appearanceiddata');
```

This is my controller excerpt:

```
public function appearanceiddata()
    {
        //$magic = DB::table('prog_title')->select('pr_id', 'pr_title')->get();
        $magic = DB::table('prog_title')->select('pr_id', 'pr_title')-> where('pr_index', '=', 1)->get();
        return view ('takealook', ['magical' => $magic]);
    }
```

Comment: Have a look at [Middelware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware), you can use that to check if the logged in user equals a certain user, and redirect them accordingly.

Comment: My Authenticate.php file is the default. This section should be edited?       public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->auth->guest()) {
            if ($request->ajax()) {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            } else {
                return redirect()->guest('auth/login');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

Answer (score 0):

This is a short fix for your problem.

```
public function appearanceiddata()
    {
        if (!Auth::guard('web')->check()) //check if someone is logged in
            {
                 //redirect to login page. 
            }
        else {
           /*Check if the logged in user is your desired user. 
            Maybe try matching the logged in id with your desired id. 

           If you find that a user is logged in but they are not your desired user 
            then you may redirect them in some other place or show them a message. */
              }
        //$magic = DB::table('prog_title')->select('pr_id', 'pr_title')->get();
        $magic = DB::table('prog_title')->select('pr_id', 'pr_title')-> where('pr_index', '=', 1)->get();
        return view ('takealook', ['magical' => $magic]);
    }
```

However, this practice is ok if you have one or two restricted field. But if you have more than that then you should read about [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware).

Comment: This gives me error (FatalThrowableError in KedivimController.php line 68:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'public' (T_PUBLIC)).  What I had in my mind (but do not know if correct) was to edit some auth file and add username & password and then add this to route I want to have restricted access...

Comment: I didn't write the code as I don't know your login address, how you check the desired user etc. I just provided some ideas. Check the commented part.

Comment: Another thought is to create a db table with my desired username and password and ask user to fill form with those credentials. If they are correct the page should open. But I did not want to do it this way. I thought it would be an easier way.